# trying to make a textbox populate a variable that changes every three seconds

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to make a text box in a WPF C# application populate a text box from a variable gathered from an external database using WCF and having little luck. Currently the text box states ScoreBoardClientTest.FeedServiceAgent instead of the value of agentsavailable. I was able to make this exact same code work in a console application when using this line of code inside of OnMessageReceived

```
console.writeline(e.cmsdata.skill.agentsavailable.tostring());
```

so I assumed I could do something similar here.
any help understanding where I'm going wrong would be great.

DisplayNumber is the name of the textbox.

```
public void TextBlock_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {                        
            using (var data = new FeedServiceAgent())
            {
                data.MessageReceived += OnMessageReceived;             

                data.Subscribe("92", 3);
                DisplayNumber.Text = data.ToString();              
            }           
        }

        public static void OnMessageReceived(object sender, MessageReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (e == null)
                    return;

                if (e.CmsData == null)
                {
                    e.CmsData.Skill.AgentsAvailable.ToString();
                }

               // if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Message))
               //     Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //    logger.Error(" Exception " + ex);
                //    throw ex;

            }
        }
```

Comment: Utilize breakpoints to debug your application. Check the value of the variables `data` and `e.CmsData.Skill.AgentsAvailable`.

Comment: `DisplayNumber.Text = data.ToString();` sets the `TextBox.Text` to whatever `ToString()` generates which is usually just the type's name - which is what you're seeing. Also, `e.CmsData.Skill.AgentsAvailable.ToString();` doesn't actually use the value in anyway. Try `DisplayNumber.Text = e.CmsData.Skill.AgentsAvailable.ToString();` in your `OnMessageReceived` handler.

Comment: when I use a break point to determine what data is seeing its exactly like you say, the types name. when I add displayNumber.text = e.cmsdata.skill.agentsavailable.tostring(); I get an error on displaynumber because its not on the method attached to the textbox. also just to add the data.subscribe is needed because it states what queue the data is pulling from.

Comment: @mcavanaugh418 The .ToString(); method is derived from object and at default it returns the type name. If you want to display specific data you have to override it in the specific class. Please show us code for FeedServiceAgent and AgentsAvailable.

Comment: I assumed `DisplayNumber` was the name of the TextBox. Also, in your description you reference `e.cmsdata.skills.agentsavailable.ToString()` but your code references `.CmsData.Skill.AgentsAvailable.ToString();` Note the 's' on the first 'skils'. So it's a little unclear what's actually going on. Is `CmsData` of the Type `FeedServiceAgent`? if so you can just navigate out changing `data.ToString();` to `data.Skill{s}.AgentsAvailable.ToString();` Might be useful to post a bit more code.

Comment: In line with @burnsi 's comment, posting your XAML wouldn't hurt either

Comment: I believe I added all the requested code except for the XAML which is literally only a textbox with margins

Comment: i can't override the code. it states there is nothing to override.

Comment: @mcavanaugh418 please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

Changed:
`DisplayNumber.Text =e.CmsData.Skill.AgentsAvailable.ToString();`
to:
`Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)(() => { DisplayNumber.Text = e.CmsData.Skill.AgentsAvailable.ToString() ; }`

This will handle multithreaded calls. You might have to add a using System.Threading statement for the `DispatcherPriority` enum

**EndEdit**

It is still unclear how to get from the `data` of Type `FeedServiceAgent` to a `Skill.AgentsAvailable` property in your `Loaded` event handler. We need more information on how to make that navigation. Is the assignment even necessary in the `Loaded` handler? I've marked the location in the code below.

I've also made what appears to be the necessary changes to the message handler method.

```
public void TextBlock_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {                        
        using (var data = new FeedServiceAgent())
        {
            data.MessageReceived += OnMessageReceived;             

            data.Subscribe("92", 3);
            //DisplayNumber.Text = data.ToString();

            //Is this assignment even necessary?
            DisplayNumber.Text = /*Still unclear what goes here because we don't know what how to get from `data` to `Skill`*/            
        }           
    }

    public static void OnMessageReceived(object sender, MessageReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e == null)
                return;

            if (e.CmsData == null)
            {
                //e.CmsData.Skill.AgentsAvailable.ToString();
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)(() => { DisplayNumber.Text = e.CmsData.Skill.AgentsAvailable.ToString() ; }));
            }

           // if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Message))
           //     Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //    logger.Error(" Exception " + ex);
            //    throw ex;

        }
    }
```

Comment: data to skill happens inside on onmessagereceived. MessageReceived is part of feedserviceagent which allows me to call cmsdata in OnMessageReceived. so data.messageReceived from feedservice agent plus the skill from cmsdata in onmessagereceived should display the data specified. in this case logged in agents in certain phone queue which is 8(obviously this number is only reflecting the time period when i'm typing this and is always changing)

Comment: Yes, I follow that part. What is unclear is what information you want to set `TextBox.Text` to inside the `TextBox_Loaded` handler. I don't see a `MessageReceived` member on `FeedServiceAgent` so it appears this information is only be available inside `OnMessageReceived`. If this is the case, perhaps the text box should be empty until a message is received. If the value never gets updated then follow @burnsi's advice and step through and find out why it's not ever getting to the setter.

Comment: public event MessageReceivedEventHandler MessageReceived; is inside of feedserviceagent line 26 for me

Comment: Yes, that's what will invoke the `OnMessageReceived` handler in your window class. This has nothing to do with the `TextBox_Loaded` handler. I suspect the line in `TextBox_Loaded` should be `DisplayNumber.Text = null;` (or string.Empty) because when the form and text box first load, there isn't a message to display information about. That's why you subscribe to the event. There is likely another issue that is preventing `OnMessageReceived` from ever setting the text value. Have you set a breakpoint on that line? or on the first `if` statement to make sure the method is even being called?

Comment: Just read your reply to @burnsi. Try setting a breakpoint at ` if (MessageReceived != null)
` in `FeedServiceAgent.ProcessCmsData'. This will tell you if the agent is even raising the event and just keep working backwards until you find why the event isn't being raised.

Comment: ok so i just added a breakpoint to the if statements in the line inside of the if statements inside of OnMessageReceived. When i look at the data it throws it can see cmsdata.skills and all the different skills and is updating. but the message is null. So the if statements have access to the data i need. the question is now simply how to pull that data into the textblock

Comment: i feel like this would be easier if i knew how to do WPF data bindings

Comment: the message? what specific property on which specific object?

Comment: I've added a photo to the main post. take a look

Comment: please change: e.CmsData.Skill.AgentsAvailable.ToString();
 to: DisplayNumber.Text = e.CmsData.Skill.AgentsAvailable.ToString();

Comment: For the purposes of updating the text box you don't need the Message property on `MessageEventArgs` to be anything. You have the data you need in `e.CmsData.Skill.AgentsAvailable.ToString();` you just need to actually assign it to `DisplayNumber.Text`

Comment: nothing gets updated. no data gets placed into the textbox

Comment: set a breakpoint on the close brace right after that line and inspect `DisplayNumber.Text` property to see if it has changed there and perhaps is being changed back somewhere else

Comment: interesting development. If i do not have DisplayNumber.Text = data.ToString(); inside of textbox_loaded then OnMessageReceived if statement for displaynumber.text=e.CmsData.skill.agentsavailable.tostring(); never gets called

Comment: that is interesting. I also just realized you are probably having a multithreading issue. working on an edit to my answer. shouldn't take more than a couple of minutes...

Comment: Changed the code above. As for the 'interesting' bit, I can't see any reason why setting `DisplayNumber.Text` in `Textbox_Load` should have any effect on `OnMessageReceived` but if it makes it work leave it in - at least for now.

Comment: had to add a few missing )); at the end of the line you changed but holy crap it worked. you sir...amazing. thank you so much. was also able to remove the displaynumber.text in textbox_load now

Comment: Glad we got through it.